# Show table border when printing from firefox,IExplorer

Tags: javascript, printing

I'm attempting to print a part of a page in firefox and IE, the print view works fine in Chrome, but does not work in Firefox or IE. There are no errors thrown that I see.

Any ideas?

Here is my css.

```
@media print{
    #header { display:none; }
}
body { font-size:16px; }
#footer { display:none; }

table {
    font-size:16px; margin-top:2px; 
    border:solid #000 !important;
    border-width:1px 0 0 1px !important;
}
th, tr {
    width: 100px; 
    text-align:right;
    padding-right: 5px; 
    border:solid #000 !important;
    border-width:0 1px 1px 0 !important;
}

tbody td { width:130px; text-align:right;padding-right: 5px; border:1px solid #000; }
h4 { font-size: 1.2em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.3em; }
```

Here is my print function:

```
function printAllTable(id) {
            var html = "<html>";
            html += "<head>";
            html += "</head><body>";
            html += document.getElementById("allcompheader").innerHTML;
            html += document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
            html += "</body></html>";
            var printview = window.open('', '', 'width=950,height=900');
            printview.innerWidth = screen.width;
            printview.innerHeight = screen.height;
            printview.screenX = 0;
            printview.screenY = 0;
            printview.document.write(html);
            printview.print(); 
        }
```

html....

```
<input id="printCombinedSummary" type="button" value="Print" onclick="printAllTable('AllCompanySummaryTable')"/>
```

Comment: wouldn't you need "1px " in front of "solid #000"? I think the default width is zero?

Comment: @Shanimal , that is addressed with :   border-width:0 1px 1px 0 !important;  and  border-width:1px 0 0 1px !important;

Comment: Both IE and FF have an user option, which controls background printing. Make sure your "Page options" allows to print background colors and images.

Comment: how strange. I was talking about the td values, which magically didn't make it from my clipboard to the jsfiddle window o_O ...